# yaml.safe_load returns string instead of object

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

I have this piece of code:

```
    config_object = yaml.safe_load(config_string)
    print("passed config: {}".format(config_object)) 
    ^^ prints expected yaml structure

    print("deserialized config object type: {}".format(type(config_object)))
    ^^ prints deserialized config object type: <class 'str'>

    value = config_object["field1"]["field2"]["field3"]
    ^^  Error: string indices must be integers
```

My yaml config:

```
   ---
   field1:
     field2:
       field3: value
     field4: value
   ...
```

I do not understand why string is returned. And I do not see any string return type here: https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: Your example works fine for me: https://repl.it/repls/EthicalPrettyCopyleft

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with different data:

```yaml
train:images/train
```

I solved the issue by **adding a space after the colon**:

```yaml
train: images/train
```

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to wrap your function argument with `open()` as follows:

```
config_object = yaml.safe_load(open(config_string))
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, that trying to load ... most any invalid YAML data, returns a `str` (with both `yaml.load` and `yaml.safe_load`).
I would say, that is very bad, but... that's how it is.
I accidentally tried to load TOML files with `yaml.load`,
and it also just returns the TOML file content as a string,
without any error.

### General Solution

Parse your YAML data with something else,
be it an other YAML library (possibly in an other language then Python)
or in an IDE with YAML parsing support,
figure out the problem, fix it,
and then go back to using `yaml.load`
with the now valid YAML data.